# Facebook App Permissions: ads_read vs read_insights

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Could someone please clarify what is the difference between [`ads_read`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/ads_read/) and [`read_insights`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/read_insights/) permissions? My use case is the following: I have a FB app which can be used to help user create ad campaigns. What I want to do is to get basic statistics for those campaigns (clicks, impressions, ctr) and display it to the user. Which one of these permissions should I request? Both seem to allow for some kind of analytics and dashboard building.

Answer (score 0):

> Which one of these permissions should I request?

**Both**

In your use case, it looks like you don't need to send data, so `read_insights` should do the work.

But [ads_read](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/ads_read) and [read_insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/read_insights) have the exact same note :

> "You may also use this permission to request analytics insights to improve your app and for marketing or advertising purposes, through the use of aggregated and de-identified or anonymized information"

And [this tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/read_insights) suggest to use both too